# Python cv2.imread() by url

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

i want to get images by url here on 6 and 7 lines, any help or ideas?

````
import urllib
import numpy as np
mkembed = ""
ourembed = ""
mkpic = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
ourpic = cv2.imread("image2.jpg")
difference = cv2.subtract(mkpic, ourpic)
b, g, r = cv2.split(difference)
if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) == 0:
    print("The images are completely Equal")```
````

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to get an image by url with cv2:

```
 #import necessary packages
 import numpy as np
 import urllib.request as urllib
 import cv2

 #get image by url
 resp = urllib.urlopen("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png")
 image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
 image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

 #show image
 cv2.imshow("Image", image)
 cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: I installed python-Pillow and now i got AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request' error..

Comment: Embedding works but cv2.imread not works with urling.. :/ https://i.imgur.com/FSUo0KY.png